# Google Device Access: Filter device types during authorisation

Tags: nest-device-access

I'm looking to integrate Nest doorbell and cameras with my app using the new Google Device Access API.

When following the authorisation flow in the user guide (https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize), the user is presented with the option to select which devices to connect with our app. Is there a way to filter this so that only devices with camera capability/traits will show?

Currently all devices seem to show (e.g. thermostats), but my app will only be able to use the camera traits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a way to filter those at this time.